# VIM mapping an internal command

Tags: vim

I can't figure out how to map an internal command in vim.
I want to map to the command :Indent, the action `g=GG` (indenting the whole document)
I did this :

```
:command Indent execute "g=GG"
```

And it doesn't seem to work.
I successfully mapped

```
 :command Java execute ":!javac *.java; echo ' **** done **** ' "
```

but how do i make it compile only the file that i am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gg=G` is a normal mode command. You need to use `:normal`, here:

```
:command! Indent normal! gg=G
```

But… `:Indent<CR>` is much longer than `gg=G` so I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: I go under the assumption that i will forget gg=G very soon. It worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need either. Still, if you want a command, at least let's have it support ranges:

```
:command! -range=% -nargs=0 Indent <line1>,<line2>normal! ==
```